# How to add persistent connection support to a load-balanced HTTP webservice

Tags: haproxy, web-services, keep-alive

We are working on an HTTP webservice load-balanced using haproxy. The webservice is accessed via SSL. It is a RESTful HTTP service and simply accepts JSON, does some work, and returns JSON. There is no notion of a session.

We have redundant load-balancers set up in front of a pair of redundant webservice servers. Each server sits behind Apache, where Apache is used as a proxy in order to handle SSL and logging. If it matters, our webservice is a Clojure (java) application using compojure (jetty) to handle HTTP.

This is a brief diagram showing the path of a client request through our existing system.

`client request -> haproxy (load balancing) -> apache (ssl, logging) -> webservice`

We would like any connection to the load-balancer to establish a persistent connection and then be served by the same server for all subsequent requests sent through that persistent connection. In other words, we don't want a persistent connection to haproxy making requests to more than one webservice server.

How would you recommend that we get this working? How can we "pin" a given connection to the load-balancer to a specific webservice server? How could we prevent accidentally loading down a specific webservice server with multiple intensive requests?

Comment: I think the general term you are looking for here is "sticky session".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `balance source` in the `defaults` block, along with removing `option httpclose` entries did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for HAProxy's `cookie` directive, which will ensure that clients stick to the same backend.

As far as avoiding overloading a given backend, you'll be completely dependent on the initial load balancing - moving clients to a different server mid-session doesn't fit with session persistence being enforced from the load balancer.  If the load issue is a big one, then maybe reconsider having HAProxy do session persistence, keeping a centralized session state among the backends instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks. A cookie won't be useful in this case because the webservice does not interact with browsers and is sessionless.